# Adding dynamic group as member of another dynamic group

Tags: entra-id

**In Azure AD, is it impossible for dynamic groups to be added to other dynamic groups?**

What I'm trying to achieve:

- dyn-sub-group:
  It should automatically include all person of department `DepSub`
- dyn-main-group:
  It should automatically include all persons of department `DepMain`
  It should *also* include all members of dyn-sub-group.

The dynamic includes works fine, but making `dyn-sub-group` a member of `dyn-main-group` simply fails, with no error details but the generic "Failed to add group member".

I was succesful however, in adding `dyn-sub-group` to `dyn-main-group` when I changed the main group to use the membership type `Assigned`, but that defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do.

My usecase here is, that I'd like to setup a dynamic group that adds users from e.g. a Department attribute, but a subgroup in that group belongs to a sub department instead,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For membership type of group, there are **assigned**, **dynamic user** and **dynamic device**. The assigned group need manually to add or remove members without rules.
The dynamic group (dynamic user and dynamic device) can automatically add and remove its members depending on the configured rules.

For you, both dyn-sub-group and dyn-main-group are dynamic group, they have different rules and they automatically add and remove members.

> The dynamic includes works fine, but making dyn-sub-group a member of
>   dyn-main-group simply fails, with no error details but the generic
>   "Failed to add group member".

You cannot manually add one dynamic group to another dynamic group with the different rules.

Comment: But can I dynamically add the groups then? I can't seem to find any road to making it work? The dynamic rules seems to be targeted directly at users and not at groups?

Comment: Of course, the dynamic group is targeted directly at users and devices with rules. For the details, you can read this from this link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-dynamic-membership

Comment: No of course for me there. I find it rather counter intuitive that I can't have my setup working entirely through dynamic setups. Giving the structure more thought, I've found that it works pretty ok, by having dynamic groups always have a non-generic parent group. Then adding other groups side by side becomes easy again. Thanks for clearing it up. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this.